# Display pokemons on the map with delay

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm experiencing a very frustrating problem.

When I'm out to play pokemon go I have to wait (most of the time between 30 to 2 minutes) for pokemon to appear on my device.

This is how it happens: I'm hunting with a friend and she tells me that Haunter is around. However, I don't see any and have to wait for appear to me. Same happens when driving a car or bus. On her phone, pokemons are showing, but not on mine.
Sometimes restarting the app solves the problem, but only if location is confirmed.

We even use the same phones.

Do any of you also has this problem?

Comment: Any chance your internet connection is intentionally slowed down by your ISP? If that's the case, this may introduce significant lag in everything network/internet related, not just Pokemon GO.

Comment: I'm using LTE mobile connection and my friend too. We have the same ISP. Connection seems to work fine, for example I use TeamViewer without any visible delay.

Comment: Do they have wifi on while you have wifi off by any chance?

Comment: No they don't. We don't use wifi at all.

Comment: Do you have all updates installed?

Comment: Yes, I have updated phone software and all installed applications.

Comment: GPS settings set to max accuracy?

Comment: Yes, + I have checked "Scanning always available" in wifi options. Location on map is shown correctly.

Comment: What device/os are you running the app on?

Comment: I'm running Pokemon Go on brand new samsung galaxy j5, android 5.1.1